# Retrieve XML attribute value based on previous attribute value VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve the attribute "value" if "key" = PublicAddresses[PRIMARY][0]. I am very new at this and I am trying to learn VB.Net as I go.

Here is my xml document layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE preferences SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">
<preferences EXTERNAL_XML_VERSION="1.0">
  <root type="system">
    <map/>
    <node name="Level1">
      <map/>
      <node name="current">
        <map/>
       <node name="PublicIdentity">
          <map>
            <entry key="PublicAddresses[PRIMARY][0]" value="192.168.1.1"/>
            <entry key="PublicAddresses[SECONDARY][0]" value="192.168.1.2"/>
          </map>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </root>
</preferences>
```

Here is what I have come up with, very spaghetti like:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim XmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    XmlDoc.Load("prefs.xml")
    For Each Element As XmlElement In XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*")
        For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In Element.Attributes
            If Attribute.Name = "value" Then
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", Attribute.Value)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using google to search StackOverflow I was able to find this gem:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534623/querying-xml-with-linq-by-attribute)

and here is my solution:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("prefs.xml")
    Dim primaryKey = "PublicAddresses[PRIMARY][0]"
    Dim secondaryKey = "PublicAddresses[SECONDARY][0]"
    Dim priResult = doc.Descendants("entry").Where(Function(user) CType(user.Attribute("key"), String) = primaryKey).SingleOrDefault
    Dim secResult = doc.Descendants("entry").Where(Function(user) CType(user.Attribute("key"), String) = secondaryKey).SingleOrDefault

    If priResult IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim primaryIPAddress = CType(priResult.Attribute("value"), String)
        Console.WriteLine(primaryIPAddress)
    End If
    If secResult IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim secondaryIPAddress = CType(secResult.Attribute("value"), String)
        Console.WriteLine(secondaryIPAddress)
    End If
End Sub
```